# Find a child element with specific text (value) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, element

I have a tree that is inside a `<div>` tag (id: treePanel).
This tree is actually a bunch of `<ul> and <li>` tags that are nested in several levels (`<ul>` tag inside another `<ul>` tag and so on.

I need to find a node in this tree (one of the `<li>` tags) that has a specific text and update it. How can I do this using jQuery?

Example:

```
<div id="treePanel">
<ul>
  <li> root 1</li>
  <li> root 2</li>
  <li> root 3
  <ul>
    <li> leaf1</li>
    <li> leaf2</li>
    <li> find me</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I need to find a node in this tree (one of the tags) that has a
>   specific text and update it

Use `:contains` <sup>[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)</sup> filter selector:

```
$('#treeID li:contains("your text")').......
```